# Slow query in SQL server when using microseconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I run a query that filters on date, if I run the exact same query twice, the first time with my_date_field = '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and the second with my_date_field = '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000', the first one (without microseconds) runs faster. Is that normal? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Some more background, the execution plans are the same when I run the queries in SSMS. I'm not even sure if I'd get any slowness there. I see the slowness in a PHP application using the native SQL Server driver. I noticed the slowness because there's a loop that runs a query more than once (yeah, I know, to avoid if possible, but hard to avoid here) and the more records you get, the more you notice the slowness. With 100 records, the process runs fast without microseconds and is upwards of 40 seconds with them.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the comments that got me digging deeper. Changing the microseconds mad things faster, but it's just a coincidence. After much debugging, I discovered that absolutely any change in the way the query is results in a faster query. As in, I can add a space somewhere or remove a carriage return and it's fast. So my guess is that there's some flawed execution plan that's cached somehow. Only thing that has me a puzzled is that the query parameters are bound, so while I can see how changing the query would fix things, I'm surprised changing the data for that date param fixes it. Maybe I've got that wrong though. Problem is, if it caches the execution plan for the data, how do I get it to update execution plan to something that makes sense?

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: Yeah, they're identical.

Comment: please show us your query.

Comment: also, share the plan `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON`

Comment: So you don't actually know that it's the SQL query that's slower.  Could be something else in the app.   Have you tried putting some timers in the app before and after the sql call to see if that's where the time difference occurs?   Also, can you replace sending your datetime parameter as a string with sending it as a datetime?

Comment: Is the first one returning more rows?

Comment: Thanks for the comments that got me digging deeper. Changing the microseconds mad things faster, but it's just a coincidence. After much debugging, I discovered that absolutely any change in the way the query is results in a faster query. As in, I can add a space somewhere or remove a carriage return and it's fast. My guess is that there's some flawed execution plan that's cached. Only thing that has me a puzzled is that the query parameters are bound, so while I can see how changing the query would fix things, surprised changing the data for that param fixes it. Updating question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was run sp_updatestats and performance improved quite a bit.